# Kernel of a polynomial with matrix, $ker(p(A))$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Let $A\in Mat(3,3,\mathbb R)$ a matrix and $\chi_A(x)=p_1(x)\cdot p_2(x)$ the characteristic polynomial. Evaluate $ker(p_1(A))$.$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix},p_1(x)=x-2$$

What do I have to do? I know how to calculate the kernell of matrix but not from $p_1(A)$

Answer (score 0):

As always, when applying a polynomial on a matrix, the result is again a matrix. In this case, we have $p_1(A)=A-2E_3$, where $E_3$ denotes the $3\times 3$-identity matrix. So you first calculate $p_1(A)$ and afterwards the kernel.

Comment: Thank you. Tomorrow I will post the evaluated answer.